# What is the magic of scribd.com?

Tags: pdf, html

Scribd.com shows pdfs produced by TeX in HTML format, its HTML version is 100% like pdf one. How it's possible? Is there a tool for doing that publicly available?

For example see http://www.scribd.com/doc/65397968/xepersian

Comment: some of the techniques are described here http://coding.scribd.com/2010/05/17/facing-font-in-html/  (but it doesn't involve tex at all so I think it's off topic)

Answer (score 2):

There is [Pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), maybe you could rig something like scribd for yourself with it. You might need to install it on your server and start to twiddle with the [JavaScript API](http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/edit#html,live), but at least it's an available implementation that should once find it's ways into the official Firefox code base.

Comment: Could you flesh out this answer a bit? Otherwise it's a bit thin for an answer of itself and should probably be a comment.

Comment: @doncherry I'm not really, really familiar with Pdf.js, just stumbled over it recently. The question was if there's such a tool publicly available, so I presumed my answer would be a valid one... I've added an example to my answer, what do you think now?